# Does the equation $5{\sqrt{6x^2-19x-20}}+\frac{1}{4}{\sqrt{4(x^2+1)-17x}}=0$ have any real solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

For all value of $x$, ${\sqrt{6x^2-19x-20}}>0$  and ${\sqrt{4(x^2+1)-17x}}>0$.  Does the equation $5{\sqrt{6x^2-19x-20}}+\frac{1}{4}{\sqrt{4(x^2+1)-17x}}=0$ have any real solutions? Any how to obtain the solutions?

Comment: If $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, is it possible $ka + lb = 0$ if $k > 0$ and $l > 0$?

Comment: Use the fact that if $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=0$ and $a$ and $b$ are real then $a=0$ and $b=0$.

Comment: Your first sentence is false.  For $x = 4$, $6(4)^2 - 19(4) - 20 = 0$ and its square root is $0$.  For $x =1$ in the same polynomial, the result is not real, so is not positive.  The second radicand *also* has a zero at $x = 4$, so it not always positive and *also* is not real valued at $x = 1$, so is not positive there either.

Comment: So the first sentence may be false as the answer to the square roots may or may not be greater than zero.  For the equation in the 2nd sentence to be zero, $6x^2-19x-20$ must be zero and $4(x^2+1)-17x$ must be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $6x^2-19x-20=(x-4)(6x+5)$ and $4(x^2+1)-17x=(x-4)(4x-1)$.

Hence $x=4$ is the only real solution.